# Number of decimal places on edges of a decision-tree plot with ggparty

Tags: r, ggplot2, decision-tree

I want to plot a decision tree (as estimated by the partykit package) using the powerful ggparty package. Everything is fine except for the number of decimal places of numeric split variables. How can I format the `breaks_label` in `geom_edge_label()`, for example, to change `> 75.33333` into `> 75.3` in the plot below? `round()` does not work. I might use a workaround via the general `options(digits = 3)`, but I am wondering whether there is a more direct way.

```r
library("ggparty") 
data("WeatherPlay", package = "partykit")

sp_o <- partysplit(1L, index = 1:3)
sp_h <- partysplit(3L, breaks = 75 + 1/3)
sp_w <- partysplit(4L, index = 1:2)
pn <- partynode(1L, split = sp_o, kids = list(
    partynode(2L, split = sp_h, kids = list(
        partynode(3L, info = "yes"),
        partynode(4L, info = "no"))),
    partynode(5L, info = "yes"),
    partynode(6L, split = sp_w, kids = list(
        partynode(7L, info = "yes"),
        partynode(8L, info = "no")))))
py <- party(pn, WeatherPlay)

ggparty(py) +
    geom_edge() +
    # geom_edge_label() +
    geom_edge_label(mapping = aes(label = paste(breaks_label))) +
    geom_node_splitvar() +
    geom_node_info()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: ```geom_edge_label(mapping = aes(label = paste(round(breaks_label,1)))``` doesn't work??

Comment: No, it errors with `non-numeric argument to mathematical function`. The thing seems to be that `breaks_label` is some kind of special object that gets parsed to be able to add the (in)equality signs in front of it. See also https://github.com/martin-borkovec/ggparty/wiki/5-geom_edge_label.

Comment: it's really quite tough, you are correct it doesn't work because pyplot$data$breaks_label, you get a text.. I tried to change the label inside the party object but it was rendered invalid after the change...

Comment: most likely a more general solution is to use regex and alter pyplot$data$breaks_label and replot it .. though i don't know if thats a feasible solution for you

Comment: I see, altering the strings in `pyplot$data$breaks_label` allows me to get to the desired solution---even though in a very indirect way. If no direct solutions comes up, I would accept your answer if you want to take the time and post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for using ggparty!

So I think, this is something for which there's really no straight-forward solution with the current version. But I'll make sure to implement it in the future!

Generally, through using the geoms only on subsets of the nodes, one can usually work around quite a lot of stuff. As you have already noticed, the breaks_label are not stored as numeric but as character with some parsable text for the inequality signs infront of them. Therefore you'll have to use something like substr().

```
ggparty(py) +
  geom_edge() +
  geom_edge_label(id = -c(3, 4)) +
    geom_edge_label(mapping = aes(label = paste(substr(breaks_label, start = 1, stop = 15))),
                    id = c(3, 4)) +
  geom_node_splitvar() +
  geom_node_info()
```

I also modified one of the internal functions to include the rounding feature, so you can get it from github and use it. But I haven't really tested it, so use at your own risk ;)

```
library(devtools)
source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-borkovec/ggparty/martin/R/add_splitvar_breaks_index_new.R")

rounded_labels <- add_splitvar_breaks_index_new(party_object = py,
                                                plot_data = ggparty:::get_plot_data(py), 
                                                round_digits = 2)

ggparty(py) +
  geom_edge() +
  geom_edge_label(mapping = aes(label = unlist(rounded_labels)),
                  data = rounded_labels) +
  geom_node_splitvar() +
  geom_node_info()
```